# javascript callback function to update span

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the jQuery plugin minddust/bootstrap-progressbar to animate progress bars.

http://www.minddust.com/project/bootstrap-progressbar/demo/bootstrap-3-1-1/#m-custom-percentage-format

I also have a span tag `class="updatePrecent"` with the percentage text beside each of the progress bars which I wish to animate. The plugin has functions to animate the text inside the progress bar or animate a single span, but not text beside many progress bars.

It does have a callback function with the percentage value but my knowledge of javascript is limited and research I have done does not cove this particular situation.

There will be many progress bars produced from a loop.

```
<td>
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" data-transitiongoal="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%;" aria-valuenow="100">                                     
            <span class="sr-only">100% Complete (success)</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
<td><span class="updatePrecent"></span>%</td>
```

The script:

```
$('.progress .progress-bar').progressbar({
    transition_delay: 1500,
    percent_format: function(p) {
        return p + ' percent';
    }
});
```

I have tried this and variations of it inside the function but no effect.

```
percent_format: function(p) {
    $this.parent().next('.updatePrecent').text(p);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `update` callback and not `percent_format`.

You can do something like this

```
update: function(current_percentage, $this){
    $this.closest('td').next().find('.updatePrecent').text(current_percentage);
}
```

[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest) will match the first ancestor element and from there you can do [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) which will get the next `td` and then you have to use `find` to get the span.

Here is a demo **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/abwkorq7/5/**

Comment: sorry still no effect, I think the problem might be I am using the plugins callback function incorrectly. I am nit sure if even putting the updating of the text code in will work that way

Comment: I have used your updated suggestion of `update:` I now get an error ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $this

Comment: im sorry, I forgot to add the second parameter `$this`. Please check updated answer and try

Comment: great thanks. that has worked. I know something about passing scope but still learning. Thank you I am much clearer

Comment: I am glad. And here is a demo if it helps http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/abwkorq7/5/